# Perl DBI Connect Error ORA-21561: OID generation failed

Tags: oracle, perl

I am running a Perl Script and I am seeing this error message.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;

my $host = 'server';
my $user = 'user';
my $pwd = $ENV{'Login'};

my $driver = "Oracle";
$dsnslam = "DBI:$driver:host=$host;service_name=vps;port=1525";
$dbhslam = DBI->connect($dsnslam, "$user", "$pwd") || die "connect failed: ";
```

```
DBI connect('host=server;service_name=abc;port=1525','user',...) failed: ORA-21561: OID generation failed (DBD ERROR: OCISessionBegin)
```

I can do Tnsping and sqlplus without any issues.

I am running the script from Windows and the remote database is Oracle 19c on RHEL.I also added an entry on the Windows etc hosts file and that did not help either.

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1   localhost   WindowsServer.domain    WindowsServer
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show your code (the connection parameters at DBI->connect sentence)

Comment: Added the code. Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31338916/sqlplus-remote-connection-giving-ora-21561) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39973088/1707353)?

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I did see that and I am using the tns option and passing the variables. Still failing.